# Could this be good Q&A?

Tags: support, close-reasons

I was [asked to share](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/16915/12577) what I do to consistently hit 95% efficiency. So I decided to post it as self-answered question. But then system told me not to:

[image: Screenshot]

So, is this the case? Or should I try to post it anyway?

Answer (score 4):

**You could post it in self-skeptical manner.**

Since this efficiency is surprisingly high, there's a possibility that there may be downsides that you are unaware of. Maybe others have considered your method and simply wrote it off because of a issue your not familiar with or otherwise haven't noticed.

Worst case scenario you learn something new and decide for yourself whether the benefits continue to outweigh the problems for your purposes.

Comment: Yes, it is surprising and yes, it has it's problems - I know them, I asked about them. With next brew, I'll try to take photos as I go, maybe there are things i don't notice, but photos would show?

Comment: @Molot You asked about them on Stack Exchange? If so, why not direct people to that question (since presumably you described your process there)? If it wasn't here, post the question with your new pictures and answer it with what you already know or just include those issues in your question. That will give other people the opportunity to evaluate it and post an answer if they see anything else. Even if you did post it here, you could ask another question referencing the first, with the pictures (and maybe further skepticism) being the differentiating factor(s).

Comment: @Mołot Just realized you linked to the original question (I answered this from my phone so I guess I'll blame it on that).  I would say the process itself is worth asking about.  While the pure fact that you get 95% efficiency produces the problems you suggested, maybe there's something else about the process that will produce other issues.

Answer (score 0):

The question contains the blatantly subjective expression "*really high*".

- How high is "high"?
- At what point does it become "very" high?
- How does "very high" differ from the "surprisingly high" value mentioned in an answer?

If those values aren't well defined, the responses will be subject to each responder's  opinion of what "high", "really high", and "surprisingly high" mean.

I suspect that wording the question objectively, say as "How to get greater than 95% efficiency …?", would eliminate the subjectivity.

(Note that this principle applies to questions in almost all SE sites, not only in this one.)